# Magento 2: performance issue with Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php::render

Tags: template, performance, cms-block, magento2.4.0

I have enabled the new relic log to check the performance of the Magento 2 website.
On home page I am rendering 5 blocks with 5 template files. In new relic logs, it shows homepage takes time to render `Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php::render` function, Do you have any clue why it happening ?

Here is screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`\Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php` is **default template engine** for `.phtml` files (Magento Blocks). See `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::fetchView`.

This means that all templates are run with `$templateEngine->render($this->templateContext, $fileName, $this->_viewVars)`.

In any template file if you check `get_class($this)` you will receive instance of `\Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php`. The `$block` variable is assigned to template block. TemplateEngine has logic to pass methods to `$block`. If in you code you call `$this->getSome()` it will be translated to `$block->getSome()`.

In your example means that `Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php::render` processed 53 `.phtml` files and this took 877 ms (including any lazy logic from blocks).